# ES6 - Dynamic class extension and instanceof

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to dynamicly Instantiate a class inheritance tree and be able to type check it.
[image]

```
let myFunc = function ( Superclass = Object ) {
        return class Clickable extends Superclass {
            constructor( args ) {
                super( args );
            }
            click() {}
        };
    };
console.log(myFunc);
console.log(myFunc());
let obj = new (class Q extends myFunc() {})();
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj instanceof myFunc());
```

instanceof is returning false.

I'm thinking it's for the same reason, the following returns false.
[image]

But I'm having a hard time understanding why exactly it's returning false. 
If anything, I'd expect it to twice say "Identifier Y has already been declared".

> Is there a work around for this?
>   A (very dirty) solution is to check if Q has a method "click" defined.

Comment: Please post *your actual code* as text - images of code alone are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug - it forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: Sorry, added in the code

Comment: *"why am I allowed to declare Y here again"* That's a class *expression*. The name of a class expression does not create a variable in the enclosing scope, just like it works for function expressions. It's equivalent to `inst instanceof class {}`, since the name is optional in class expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because each time you call `myFunc`, a new class is defined then returned. Those classes are not the same so the instances can't, obviously, be instances of many classes at the same time. To proof that the classes returned are not the same, it suffice to do a simple check:

```
console.log(myFunc() === myFunc());    // false
```